# using sed to add a backslash in front of a variable

Tags: variables, sed

I have a variable and that variable only needs a '\' in front of it.
I would say that the sed command is the ideal tool for it?

I tried using single quotes, double quotes, multiple variables, combination of variables, ...
I don't get an error returned but the end result is not showing what I need it do be

```
FOLDER=$(echo `cat file.XML | grep "Value" | cut -d \" -f2`)
echo $FOLDER
sed -i "s@"$FOLDER"@"\\$FOLDER"@g" ./file.XML
echo $FOLDER
```

After execution, I get

```
$ ./script.sh
b4c17422-1365-4fbe-bccd-04e0d7dbb295
b4c17422-1365-4fbe-bccd-04e0d7dbb295
```

Eventually I need to have a result like

```
$ ./script.sh
b4c17422-1365-4fbe-bccd-04e0d7dbb295
\b4c17422-1365-4fbe-bccd-04e0d7dbb295
```

Comment: `new="\\$FOLDER"`?

Comment: ``FOLDER=`cat file.XML | grep "Value" | cut -d \" -f2`
echo $FOLDER
NEW_FOLDER="\\$FOLDER" 
sed -i "s@"$FOLDER"@"$NEW_FOLDER"@g" ./file.XML``

Doesn't work either, if you meant it like this

Comment: No. You said `I have a variable and that variable only needs a '\' in front of it`. So, if you have a variable named `FOLDER` initialized as `FOLDER="foo"` and you want the value of `FOLDER` to become `"\foo"` instead then why aren't you just doing `FOLDER="\\$FOLDER"`?

Comment: Ok, got it that but then how do I change it in my file.xml ? I need to find the folder name in the file.xml and replace that exact value with a slash in front. So now I have the means to add the slash but not how to replace it

Scratch that! I forgot to reload my file.xml after executing the script *facepalm*.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed thanks to the input of Cyrus and Ed Morton.

```
FOLDER=$(echo `cat file.XML | grep "Value" | cut -d \" -f2`)
NEW_FOLDER="\\$FOLDER"

sed -i "s@$FOLDER@\\$NEW_FOLDER@g" ./file.XML
```